# How to find client ip address instead of server ip address in asp.net c#?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ip-address

I used below code for getting IP address, but it is giving server IP address.

```
 public static string LocalIPAddress()
        {
            IPHostEntry host;
            string localIP = "";
            host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    localIP = ip.ToString();
                    break;
                }
            }

        return localIP;
    }
```

From website
    "http://whatismyipaddress.com/" I found my IP address is:

```
203.100.79.91
```

But code is providing me some different IP :

```
172.24.0.123
```

How can I get user IP instead of server ?

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: I had same problem few days back and this thread had an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285957/how-to-get-public-ip-address-of-a-user-in-c-sharp

Comment: It is giving me "::1"