# how to get the client IP from ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

In local host how to get the client IP to detect the their country name in asp.net mvc with C#.
my code is

```
string ipAddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
string ipAddress2 = Request.UserHostAddress;
```

this gives the ::1 so i need the public ip from user request

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a user's client IP address in ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735350/how-to-get-a-users-client-ip-address-in-asp-net). You can also check this one: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285957/how-to-get-the-public-ip-address-of-a-user-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You get ::1 because you should be on localhost

Comment: Can you tell me, how to get Http_accept value in asp.net-mvc5?