# How to get public IP address in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on an application wherein I want to track clients public IP address.
I don't want to use http://ipinfo.io as its an insecure connection.

Is it possible to get clients public IP address using core javascript?

Thanks

Comment: are you talking about request.connection.remoteAddress

Comment: What is your backend language? If it's Node.js, you can use request.connection.remoteAddress like @VinayPrabhakaran said

Comment: My backend language is c#

Comment: Why not track it from the server itself…?

Comment: You should have a look on how to get the ip client address from you C# code. Service like ipinfo or other are usefull to get geoip but you don't need the position in your case. It's better to avoid useless call to a third part service. If you are behind a loadbalancer, you can have a look on this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285957/how-to-get-the-public-ip-address-of-a-user-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @deceze I have two application one has java as backend and other has c#. I don't want to write logic to get ip address separately for both application hence i chose javascript.

Comment: @SBillion I agree its good to avoid calls to third part service and clients firewall may block such calls. But if capturing public IP is not possible via js then may be i need to create something similar to ipinfo and call it from js.

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem by having 2 application as backend. When do you want to track your user? Just do a basic endpoint which update the database with the ip if ip is not in the session. Call your backend like you wanted to call ipinfo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use the https connection:

```
curl -v https://ipinfo.io
```

Or you can user an other service. There is a good list of services on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript-only)

Comment: I didn't knew ipinfo.io had https connection