# Find Client Public IP Address Inside Controller of rest web API with out calling external api

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web API where I want to capture all incoming request **public IP address** inside my controller function.

Comment: Do you want to get client's IP address from `HTTPRequestMessage` or from `Request`?

Comment: Could you define what you mean by public IP address? You have already been told how in the answer below.

Comment: I want client internal IP not the hosted IP address , For reference please search whats my IP in google you will get your internal IP address.@Crowcoder

Comment: No, that is the public IP. You will never get the internal IP unless the client and server are on the same network.

Comment: I want that public Ip which is showing in what my IP in Asp.net web form the below code is working fine but I want in web API controller @Crowcoder

Comment: So, based on the wealth of detail in your question I'm guessing you are testing where the client and server are on the same network. You won't get the public IP that way. You have to make the request go out to the interwebs. Trust us, when deployed to production this will return the IP you want.

Comment: I hosted In UAT and check from mobile internet also it is taking my IPV4 IP address, not public IP Address Please check this api I want exact this ip address Url:- https://api.ipify.org?format=json
 @Crowcoder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check below code this must return you IP address of client

```
   protected string GetUser_IP()
    {
        string VisitorsIPAddr = string.Empty;
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] != null)
        {
            VisitorsIPAddr = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"].ToString();
        }
        else if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.Length != 0)
        {
            VisitorsIPAddr = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
        }
    return VisitorsIPAddr;
    }
```

For more help: [Get public IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285957/how-to-get-the-public-ip-address-of-a-user-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I already tried with this. It's returning the hosted IP address not the public IP address

Comment: @manassahu, I answered 2 similar questions still requester is not satisfied my answer. Whenever you get working function for reading client IP , just post it. your answer will help me as well as to others.

Comment: please check this API. I want IP address the same which is being returned by this API  https://api.ipify.org?format=json @Prasad telkikar