# How do I get the full IP rather than ::1?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dns, ip-address, httpcontext

I have wrote this to get client's ip address but it just gets this ::1 instead of 172.16.0.129. I want to get Ipv4 version of the ip. How do I do this?

```
return HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"] ?? HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Comment: That is IPv6 localhost isn't it?

Comment: ::1 is IPv6 short for 0:0:0:0:0:1

Comment: [What is The Difference Between IPv6 and IPv4](https://www.webopedia.com/DidYouKnow/Internet/ipv6_ipv4_difference.html)

Comment: I want to get the ipv4

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285957/how-to-get-the-public-ip-address-of-a-user-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

In IPv6 **::1** means the localhost. Your machine might well have the IP 172.16.0.129 but it's also perfectly acceptable for it to refer to itself as ::1

Try your request from another machione (I suspect this request came from the same machine as the server is sitting on)

Comment: alright but I want to get the ipv4 version even for localhost

Comment: I'm not sure that coding your software up to only deal with ipv4 is going to make it particularly resilient.. But if you make a request from another machine, and that other machine communciates with yours over ipv4 then the IP you see when pulling the http headers will likely be the ipv4 version